# How to set width for subfigures inside a table in a org-mode file?

Tags: images, org-link

I'd like to use subfigures in org-mode files. In MS Word, this could be easily done by inserting the subfigures of a figure into a table with invisible borders. Then the size of each subfigure can be adjusted as you like.

*Is there a way to use subfigures like this in Org-mode?*

I tried to set size with e.g. `#+ATTR_ORG: :width 400`, and it only works on a single figure.

So, this works with the intended figure size:

```
#+CAPTION: Test Figure 
#+NAME: fig:test0
#+ATTR_ORG: :width 400
[[file:build/test.png]]
```

But when put into a table, the specified figure size (width) is ignored. (And the actual size of the sub-figure is used, which is way too large).

```
#+CAPTION: Test Figure 
#+NAME: fig:test
#+ATTR_ORG: :width 400
| [[file:build/test.png]] | [[file:build/test.png]] |
```

I have `(setq org-image-actual-width nil)`  in my init.el. And this is under Emacs 26, Ubuntu 20.04, and Org mode version 9.3.7 (9.3.7-8-g3ed035-elpaplus). I am interested in exporting the org file to multiple targets including ODT. (So, I am looking for a generic solution.)

If the above usage is wrong, what is the correct usage to get properly sized subfigures?

**-- Update --**

This blog about [extending org link syntax](http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2015/02/05/Extending-the-org-mode-link-syntax-with-attributes/) seems relevant. I guess I am looking for an extended way of specifying the image size as part of the link, with something like this:

```
[[file:build/test.png :width 300]]
```

as in

```
#+CAPTION: Test Figure 
#+NAME: fig:test
| [[file:build/test.png :width 300]] | [[file:build/test.png :width 300]] |
```

Is this doable in org?

Comment: I don't think there is any facility in Org mode to do that for every export backend. You can probably do it for LaTeX/PDF and HTML with a back-end-specific macro, but it is not going to be simple or pretty.

Answer (score 1):

If you can live without captions on subfigures this seem to work:

```
#+CAPTION: Two subfigures
#+NAME:   fig:twofigures
\begin{figure}
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.47\textwidth]{image}
     \end{subfigure}
     \begin{subfigure}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.47\textwidth]{image}
     \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

Reference to Figure [[fig:twofigures]].
```

Comment: This only works for the LaTeX export backend in case that isn't obvious. Do note that you *can* have captions on the subfigures by using the LaTeX `caption` command, just as you would if you were writing LaTeX rather than org mode. Also note that this requires `#+latex_header: \usepackage{subcaption}` in the header.

Answer (score 1):

In case this is still relevant at all, there is [this](https://list.orgmode.org/87mty1an66.fsf@posteo.net/) post describing a possible implementation using a new link type.

I think a preferable implementation for latex would use the subcaption environment like...

```lisp
(org-link-set-parameters
 "subfig"
 :follow (lambda (file) (find-file file))
 ;; :face '(:foreground "white" :weight bold :underline t)
 :display 'full
 :export
 (lambda (file desc backend)
   (when (eq backend 'latex)
     (if (string-match ">(\\(.+\\))" desc)
         (concat
          "\\subcaptionbox{" (replace-regexp-in-string "\s+>(.+)" "" desc) "}"
          "{\\includegraphics" "[" (match-string 1 desc) "]" "{" file "}}\n\\quad\n")
       (format "\\begin{subfigure}\\includegraphics{%s}\\end{subfigure}" desc file)))))
```

I am not sure about HTML. Also, this runs into issues if you have `org-export-preserve-breaks t`